# Is it possible to create users within the project as non admin user in redmine?

Tags: redmine, account

I am using Redmine for managing our software developement, but I don't want to create users for everybody in alllll projects. is it possible to have a project manager who creates users in his own category (project)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users may register themselves in Redmine, depending on the configuration they are then automatically activated or need approval by an adminstrator. A project manager may then add them to her/his own projects.

Comment: ok thanks, in other words, without administrator you can't do much if you have public projects running. (when you don't want to let newly registered users see this) But if i only have non public projects newly registered people are assigned to nothing so they can't see anything.  And then we don't need an admin to move them into their specific group. correct? grüße nach Berlin, meine Heimat :)